# Google IAP Error: Authentication is required

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

In my application, when I try purchasing subscription, I get the error:

```
Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account
```

This dialog isn't displayed, when I make regular purchase (in-app item, not a subscription).

There is some useful information:

1. Apk is published in production. Subscriptions and in-app items worked for a long period of time.
2. There are no apks in alpha / beta testing
3. Account is correct. I've tested with other application, that offers subscriptions.
4. In-app billing is implemented using https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/ with some fixes, that were made to avoid crash / unsupported feature [implementation wasn't changed for a long period of time, so I don't think, that it's the case]
5. Subscriptions product ids are also correct.
6. I've tried on several google accounts on several differents devices. Result is the same - this dialog.

I see the error in Google IabV3Activity.class, but can't figure out what is root cause of it:

```
    BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for 
https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase
```

Any ideas?

**Updated:**
Today subscriptions started work. Still not clear, what was the reason.
We updated journal description in Google Play on the weekend. Was it the reason? - No ideas...

Comment: Check that your sign in in your google play app with right account. Also as far as i know you can't subscribe from  developer account(your app was published from that acc).

Comment: Updated question with details

Answer (score 1):

I had simular problem. All in-apps have been working except subscription.

> Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account

was on the screen and in my logs presented such records:

> response code 403 for 
>   https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase

and

> RESPONSE_CODE  = 2

which means "Network connection is down" according to [android billing reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html).

All this information was useless. Reason was that subscription hasn't been activated in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Just gone through this issue ourselves, and for us, it was an incorrect IAP ID.  We basically have two games on Google Play, the one that will end up live, "GameName", and one that will only be for testing, "GameName Test".  The bundle ID is also different, com.sixminute.gamename and com.sixminute.gamename.test

To replicate how things work on iOS (that IAPs cannot have the same name for different apps under your account), we also use different SKUs per app, com.sixminute.gamename.coinpack1 and com.sixminute.gamename.test.coinpack1.  At runtime, we get the available items for the product, but for our test game, we were getting the incorrect SKUs.

So, we *wanted* to purchase "com.sixminute.gamename.test.coinpack1", but we mistakenly requesting "com.sixminute.gamename.coinpack1" which didn't exist under the "GameName Test" bundle.

So for us, while it was saying "Authentication is required", that's absolutely incorrect messaging, and that holds through with the response code, 403 stands for "Forbidden", but sometimes that can really mean 404, "Resource not found", and I think that's correct in this case.

So for you, if you've checked everything else, make 100% sure that you're passing the correct SKU at purchase attempt, and if you're sure you are, maybe do a query http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#QueryDetails as well to make sure the SKU you're trying to purchase is 100% there, active, and all the rest.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, but as I mentioned in question, ids were correct.

Comment: My main point was that while it's talking about authentication, that can, and in our case was definitely wrong, so you may want to think about other issues in play.  For all the key signing issues that also might be affecting you, you might want to also ensure you can log in to Google Play easily too.  If that also fails, it gives more detailed logging as to what's gone wrong, and that can directly relate to why IAP isn't working either. For 100%ing that you're using the correct SKUs, have you done an inventory query on the device to see if they're available / what state they're in?

Comment: Nope, I haven't. Right now for some reason issue disappeared... No ideas why, so looks like it's not SKUs issue, but anyway thanks a log for you help. Probably this issue appear again in several days, so I will follow you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Still had the same problem, I got these errors:

```
 E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling:
 com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
                                     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
                                         at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
                                         at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
                                         at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391)
                                         at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3283)
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125)
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/finsky/billing/lightpurchase/PurchaseParams
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204) 
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255) 
                                         at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223) 
                                         at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082) 
                                         at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3283) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125) 
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 
                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 
                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams" on path: .
                                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204) 
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255) 
                                         at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223) 
                                         at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082) 
                                         at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3283) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125) 
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 
                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I also got this one:

```
E/Volley: [40089] c.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/ees/preparePurchase
```

It was a little bit weird, because some other test-purchases went absolutely right. After some searching I found out, that
**there was an empty space in this sku string:**

```
public static final String SKU_ALL = " com.xxx.xxx.all "; -> ERROR
public static final String SKU_ALL = " com.xxx.xxx.all";  -> WORKS PERFECT!
```

Hope this would help somebody!